# How to operate with multiple assembly versions in private folders using config?

Tags: .net, assemblies, version, configuration-management, assemblybinding

I have a scenario where I have multiple versions of the same assembly that I need to store in the application private folders, in a structure like this:

```
.\My.dll          // latest version, say 1.1.3.0
.\v1.1.1\My.dll   // version 1.1.1.0
.\v1.1.2\My.dll   // version 1.1.2.0
```

My problem is that the .Net runtime, when asked for one of the older versions, always finds the latest version and then fails due to build number mismatch before trying to probe for a better match.

The assemblies are strong named and I'm using this configuration in my app.config:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="My" 
                publicKeyToken="xxxxxxxx" culture="netural" />

                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.1.0" 
                    newVersion="1.1.1.0" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.3.0-1.1.65535.65535" 
                    newVersion="1.1.3.0" />

                <codeBase version="1.1.1.0" href="v1.1.1\My.dll" />
                <codeBase version="1.1.2.0" href="v1.1.2\My.dll" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Hopefully there is something I have missed here. I know this can be solved in code by listening for the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event but I would love to see a pure config solution.

**Update:** So I found the bug, which is as Kent assumed, a typo. `culture="netural"` should be `culture="neutral"`.
That said, without the typo, resolving works great when using `codeBase` elements that point to each version. 
The probing element does not seem to work in this scenario.

Comment: Is this the bug: `<codeBase version="1.1.2.0" href="v1.1.2\My.dll" />` should point to `1.1.3.0` instead?

Comment: @minghan - no, look for a typo, not a logical bug :) yes, it is hard to spot. Even so that I had to consult SO for help before I spotted it myself.

Comment: `culture="netural"` should be `culture="neutral"`

Comment: @minghan indeed! If there where an award for completing an 8-year old typo hunt exercise, I would award you that :) Now it's probably time to update the text to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the entire solution, I can only assume you have a typo somewhere. I just tried this for myself and - with the help of [fuslogvw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(vs.71).aspx), I was able to get it working.

I have three versions of the assembly and the consuming application references an older version than that in its output directory. The CLR finds the redirects and codeBase entry and loads the correct (older) version.

I can email you my solution if you provide an email address.

Kent

Comment: Hmm, sorry, seems that my catch-all is not working. Could you please resend to peter at dezibel.com ?

Comment: Mind not to include any executables in that mail though, most systems block such content even if they are "hidden" in zip-files..

Comment: When is SO make this kind of thing easier? OK, resent it without any bin/obj folders in it. The only time I've seen a mail system that inspects zip files was at an investment bank, and it drove everyone nuts. People just renamed their zip files to *.zip.renamed

Comment: I got a delivery failure notification for your underlying gmail address.

Comment: I got the source, Kent, thanks. Me too vote for SO features for better user-to-user interaction. Anyways, your code is working fine, but while trying it out in various ways I realized that there is more to my problem than I have described here. Update coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a probepath? we use this to force uncontrolled (e.g. third party resolvers - such as MSTest) to look for assemblies where we need them to be.

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="v1.1.1;v1.1.2;"/>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb.aspx) for more info

Comment: Hm, I have to withdraw my vote. It seems that I cannot get this to work only using the probing tag.