# WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.0.0 - exception could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, .net-standard

I developed a .NET Standard 2.0 Nuget package (local) for a class library with a dependency on WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.0.0. It passed unit tests and ran fine when invoked from a .NET Core 2.0 console app. However, when I added my package to an Azure Function project (.Net Standard 2.0) it caused an exception to be thrown whenever I attempted to run the azure function from the VS2017 debugger.

> System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly
>      'WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>      PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60

I had the same sort of problem with Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.1.1.0 and this was resolved by downgrading to v2.0.0.0 - see [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614750/microsoft-extensions-configuration-version-2-1-1-0-exception-could-not-load-f)

**Question 1:** What version of WindowsAzure.Storage works with .NET Standard 2.0 Azure Functions?

**Question 2**: Apart from trial and error, how are people using this package meant to find out what it works with?

Comment: this can happen when a nuget package dependency doesnt line up with the application's dependency for the same package.  You will want to be sure that your application is Not already referencing that package at a lower version, and that other packages are not referencing it at a lower version.  Simple fix is to add the Storage Package directly to your main application.  As with all azure packages, its usually best to use the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to downgrade the WindowsAzure.Storage package. I am using version 7.2.1 with Azure Functions v2.

Here is the link of all the file for v1. I asked for v2 but no update yet.
https://gist.github.com/fabiocav/8fcccd4d54ec298e3b120cbc1230c02a